# Is it possible to remove Google logo?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

Is it possible to remove Google Logo placed at the bottom left of the image after been generated using `Google Static Maps`. I've read Google docs but there are no references to this issue?.

Comment: They probably want it there for branding.

Comment: It is possible.  It isn't legal to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is prohibited by Terms of Service. You cannot remove logo and any attribution. You can find this information in paragraph 10.5 (g) of [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions)

> **No removing, obscuring, or altering terms of service, links, or proprietary rights notices.** You will not:
>   remove, obscure, or alter any Google terms of service or any links to or notices of those terms, or any copyright, trademark, or other proprietary rights notices; or
>   falsify or delete any author attributions, legal notices, or other labels of the origin or source of material.

Answer (score -1):

use uBlockOrigin for example, it's a plugin for Firefox, just block logo element with right click.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. This is a question about someone using google maps on their website and wanting to hide the logo for all users