# Static map remove copyright watermark

Tags: android, google-api, google-maps-static-api

Is there any way to remove copyright string from google static map, I already checked static map styling document but didn't find any answer.
 I don't have any issue with google logo but just wanted to remove "map data ©2018 google"

[image]

Comment: I think that you will be immediately banned in google play if you remove somehow that watermark, and release app to google play, as it for sure violates google play aggreement.

Comment: Google Maps API Terms of Service prohibits removing any attribution. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41336322/5140781.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be removing their Watermark as it is against their rules and your app will not be accepted to be published.

If you want an open source map, you can use [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) and they have libraries for Android too.